# Swift - "Expected type before ->": When adding a target to a button

Tags: swift, syntax

I have the following snippet which I am trying therein to add a target to a button I have created. That gives me an error `Expected type before "->"`. What am I doing wrong? I am a newbie here in swift and kinda confused with what's going on. Anyone mind explaining me what's happening here exactly?

```
//MARK: Initialization
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder:aDecoder)

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)->()), for: .touchDown)
    addSubview(button) //This is the line that is indicated as erratic
}
```

**EDIT**
[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1) is what I am following up (one of Apple's pages). There the line is different. That way it indicates an error `Type 'RatingControl' has no member 'ratingButtonTapped'` where the member is defined inside the class.

**EDIT 2**
Following is the method `ratingButtonTapped(_:)->Void`

```
func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton){
    print("Button pressed ")
}
```

Comment: Does `ratingButtonTapped(_:)` returns value? Could you post this method?

Comment: @Idan Please look at **EDIT 2**.

Comment: I think you can remove this `->()` from the selector line.

Comment: @Idan that puts me in the situation that I still have an error `Type 'RatingControl' has no member 'ratingButtonTapped'`... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a closure `() -> ()` as a `selector`. Remove `->()`

```
#selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:))
```

and make sure that the method

```
func ratingButtonTapped(sender : UIButton) { ... }
```

or in Swift 3

```
func ratingButtonTapped(_ sender : UIButton) { ... }
```

is implemented.

The target `self` assumes that the method is implemented in the current class.

Comment: That solution worked. What was missing is underscore `_` before the `sender`. Thank you @vadian. Can you please explain me what is actually meant by underscore? Why is it so important in Swift 3?

Comment: It's a compatibility issue with Objective-C. In Swift 3 all parameter labels (including the first one) are required to be passed. The underscore character is a placeholder for an ignored first parameter label.